# Where is the Camera Codec feature available in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, codec, camera-raw

If you try to install the [Camera Codec pack for Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26829) on Windows 8, you get an error:

> This version of the Microsoft Camera Codec Pack is not compatible with Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012. You can get the codec pack through Windows Update on Windows 8.

However, I cannot see anywhere on Windows update that would suggest I can download this, even as an optional update? Is it just the case that it is not yet live, as everything filters through the RTM process, or is it hidden away as something else?

Comment: Same exact issue. I get the notice too, but I don't see it anywhere in Windows Update. I'm on Win 8 Pro x64 RTM.

Comment: @SahasKatta should see it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The codec is now available via Windows Update as part of the monthly hotfix release

Comment: Does it auto-install for all Windows 8 users? Or do I need to select this hotfix manually?

Answer (score 1):

I have been researching this too. I am using a full version of Win8 Pro from Microsoft. My best answer is that they are still developing the codec pack for 8, and plan on having it as an update for Windows once Win8 is publicly released. I'm hoping the codec pack will be released to us here in the next few weeks.

Edit: As I expected, It was pushed to me through Windows Update.